# Is it possible to DM a user from their username from a Discod.js bot

Tags: discord, discord.js

I need a Discord.js bot to DM a user if an API gives it a username. Is it possible to DM a user via a bot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://discord.js.org/): you can search [`Client.users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=users) via [`Collection.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) by comparing a user's [`User.tag`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=tag):

```js
let user = client.users.find(u => u.tag === "someUser#1234");
```

Then you can send them a DM via [`User.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=send):

```js
user.send("A message from a bot");
```

Note that **the bot and said user must at least share a server** for the bot to be able to access this user.